# toupper() and tolower() not working

Tags: c++

This is a simple piece of code to interchange the cases of alphabets in a string. Assuming that it contains only alphabets and nothing else. But it just prints the initial string, does no changes to it despite the toupper() and tolower() functions.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
char sentence[30];
int i;
cout << "enter a sentence: ";
cin.getline(sentence, 30, '\n')

for (i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (isupper(sentence[i]))
        sentence[i] = tolower(sentence[i]);
    else
        sentence[i] = toupper(sentence[i]);
}

cout << sentence;
system("pause");

}
```

Comment: `i != '\0'` when do you expect this to be true? Have you tried printing `sentence` before the loop? Why are you choosing to use `char[30]` instead of `std::string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop won't be invoked at all. You're checking the index variable `i`, not the element.

```
for (i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is not running even once.

Change it to

```
 for (i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Also it would be better to use `std:string`

```
 string str;
 getline(cin,str);
 for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
 {
....
```

You could also use `std::transform`

```
char casechange(char i)
{
    if(isupper(i))return tolower(i);
    else
    return toupper(i);
}

std::transofrm(sentence.begin(),sentence.end(),sentence.begin(),casechange);
```

Answer (score 0):

The integer `0` will compare equal to the character literal `'\0'`. This is why your loop is never entered.

```
int i = 0;
assert( i == '\0' );
```

The top of your loop equivalently `for (int i = 0; i != 0; ++i)`. You either mean to do one of two things:

Check `sentence[i]` as in `for (int i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; ++i)`

Or, use a pointer variable to iterate over the string

```
for (char *p = sentence; *p != '\0'; ++p) {
    if (isupper(*p)) {
        *p = tolower(*p);
    } else {
        *p = toupper(*p);
    }
}
```

However, you can save yourself a lot of trouble by using a `std::string` which works much more cleanly with `getline`, and allows easy use with range-based for-loops:

```
std::string sentence;
std::getline(std::cin, sentence);
for (char& c : sentence) {
    if (isupper(c)) {
        c = tolower(c);
    } else {
        c = toupper(c);
    }
}
```

Or get rid of the loop entirely using the functional approach:

```
std::for_each(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), [](char& c) { c = isupper(c) ? tolower(c) : toupper(c); });
```